# Returning a regex match in VBA (excel)

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to write a function for excel 2010 that will take a cell of unstructured text, look for something called an sdi value and, if found, return that number. The sdi value will appear as sdi ####. What I want is to return sdi and the sepecific numbers that follow it, so if the cell contains "some text sdi 1234 some more text" the function will return sdi 1234.

This is my function:

```
Function SdiTest(LookIn As String) As String
  Dim temp As String
  Dim STA As Object
  temp = ""

  Set SDI = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  SDI.IgnoreCase = True
  SDI.Pattern = "sdi [1-9]*"
  SDI.Global = True

  If SDI.Test(LookIn) Then
    temp = SDI.Execute(LookIn)
  End If

  SdiTest = temp
End Function
```

If there is no sdi number it never enters the if statement and dutifully returns the empty string. If there is an sdi number I get #VALUE!

What am I missing?

Yes, VBScript is enabled. Additionally, I am finding it frustrating to use regex in VBA, and hard to find useful info online. Links to good online resources would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need to access the matches in order to get at the SDI number. Here is a function that will do it (assuming there is only 1 SDI number per cell).

For the regex, I used "sdi followed by a space and one or more numbers". You had "sdi followed by a space and zero or more numbers". You can simply change the + to * in my pattern to go back to what you had.

```
Function ExtractSDI(ByVal text As String) As String

Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.pattern = "(sdi \d+)"
RE.Global = True
RE.IgnoreCase = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

If allMatches.count <> 0 Then
    result = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
End If

ExtractSDI = result

End Function
```

If a cell may have more than one SDI number you want to extract, here is my RegexExtract function. You can pass in a third paramter to seperate each match (like comma-seperate them), and you manually enter the pattern in the actual function call:

```
Ex) =RegexExtract(A1, "(sdi \d+)", ", ")
```

Here is:

```
Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String, _
                      Optional seperator As String = "") As String

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.pattern = extract_what
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

For i = 0 To allMatches.count - 1
    For j = 0 To allMatches.Item(i).submatches.count - 1
        result = result & seperator & allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Item(j)
    Next
Next

If Len(result) <> 0 Then
    result = Right(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))
End If

RegexExtract = result

End Function
```

*Please note that I have taken "RE.IgnoreCase = True" out of my RegexExtract, but you could add it back in, or even add it as an optional 4th parameter if you like.

Comment: TheoRose, you're welcome. If the answer works, you can click the arrow on the upper left of it to 'accept it'. :)

Comment: +1, Good stuff.  But why are you disabling screenupdating within the function?

Comment: You're right, Reafidy. I took it out. I think it's just out of habbit that I included it :) (a good habit to have, though)

Comment: Answers like this are why StackOverflow exists. Thank you so much for saving me the time of trying to roll my own.

Answer (score 0):

Just a "generalized" version of [@aevanko great function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8146688/5079799)

```
Sub TestRegEx()
 Dim TextStr As String, PatternStr As String
 TextStr = "StartStr Ab12345678 EndStr"
 PatternStr = "(([a-z]{2})([0-9]{8}))"
 Debug.Print ExtractSubStrWRegEx(PatternStr, TextStr)
End Sub

Function ExtractSubStrWRegEx(ByVal PatternStr As String,ByVal TextStr As String) As String

 Dim RE As Object
 Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

 RE.Pattern = PatternStr
 RE.Global = True
 RE.IgnoreCase = True

 Dim allMatches As Object
 Set allMatches = RE.Execute(TextStr)

 If allMatches.Count <> 0 Then
  ExtractSubStrWRegEx = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
 Else
  ExtractSubStrWRegEx = ""
 End If

End Function
```