# Excel VBA Regex Match Position

Tags: regex, excel, vba

How do I grab the position of the first matched result in a regular expression? See below.

```
Function MYMATCH(strValue As String, strPattern As String, Optional blnCase As Boolean = True, Optional blnBoolean = True) As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Dim strPosition As Integer

    ' Create regular expression.
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.Pattern = strPattern
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = blnCase

    ' Do the search match.
    strPosition = objRegEx.Match(strValue)

    MYMATCH = strPosition
End Function
```

For one, I'm not entirely certain what `.Match` is returning (string, integer, etc.). The one solution I found said I should create a `Match` object to and then grab the position from there, but unlike [vb](/questions/tagged/vb), [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) does not recognize the `Match` object. I've also seen [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146485/returning-a-regex-match-in-vba-excel) like the following, but I'm not necessarily looking for the value, just the first string placement:

```
If allMatches.count <> 0 Then
    result = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
End If
```

Somewhat ignoring any of the possible syntax errors above (mostly due to me changing variable types right and left), how do I easily/simply accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're right, my fault (I forgot that it helps everyone's reputation on this site)...besides that, I figured it out on my own...again.

Comment: However, I'll post my answer in 8 hours for the benefit for anyone else who runs into this problem.

Comment: Why 8 hours and not now?

Comment: Because I didn't have enough reputation to post immediately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `FirstIndex` to return the position of matches using the `Execute` method, ie

```
Function MYMATCH(strValue As String, strPattern As String, Optional blnCase As Boolean = True, Optional blnBoolean = True) As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Dim strPosition As Integer
    Dim RegMC

    ' Create regular expression.
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        .Pattern = strPattern
        .IgnoreCase = blnCase
        If .test(strValue) Then
            Set RegMC = .Execute(strValue)
            MYMATCH = RegMC(0).firstindex + 1
        Else
            MYMATCH = "no match"
        End If
    End With
End Function

Sub TestMe()
    MsgBox MYMATCH("test 1", "\d+")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

For the benefit of others who may be having this problem, I finally figured it out.

```
Option Explicit

Function CHAMATCH(strValue As String, strPattern As String, Optional blnCase As Boolean = True, Optional blnBoolean = True) As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Dim objPosition As Object
    Dim strPosition As String

    ' Create regular expression.
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.Pattern = strPattern
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = blnCase

    ' Do the search match.
    Set objPosition = objRegEx.Execute(strValue)
    strPosition = objPosition(0).FirstIndex

    CHAMATCH = strPosition
End Function
```

Instead of a `Match` type, just a regular `Object` type will do (considering all it's returning is a class). Then, if you want to grab the index location, just use `.FirstIndex` on the match [of your choice], or if you want the value, us `.Value`