# Excel VBA - Replacing Values with a Regular Expression Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column in excel with unformatted image links. I've highlighted the image links in the raw data below

[image]

I need an excel VBA macro to convert data like so:

[image]

I wrote a regular expression `http[s?]:\/\/.*(.png|.jpg)` to pattern match the links. Sample:

[image]

I modified the function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146485/returning-a-regex-match-in-vba-excel) to do the processing

```
Function ExtractURL(ByVal text As String) As String

Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = "(http[s?]:\/\/.*(.png|.jpg))"
RE.Global = True
RE.IgnoreCase = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

If allMatches.Count <> 0 Then
    result = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
End If

ExtractURL = result

End Function
```

How do I apply this function to replace the values in Column A?

**EDIT: CLARIFICATION/CONTEXT**

I have 1000+ image links. I simply showed 5 images to make the example straightforward. It needs to work only off of column A, since its part of a larger series of macros.

Comment: Have you tried adding an actual reference to the regex library, browse the typelib and see what members/methods are available to use?

Comment: What are you doing now and what is the problem

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Good point well made! Comment deleted.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to deploy it or what a UDF is, I don't write excel VBA that often

Comment: Put the code in a standard module then in a cell you put = ExtractURL(cellwheretextis)

Comment: So in an empty cell when you start typing =Ex then function should appear. You simply need to complete the function call by putting a cell reference inside the () which contains the text you want to extract the url from. E.g. = ExtractURL(A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to replace column A with URLs only, you may try something like this...

```
Sub ExtractURL()
Dim lr As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim RE As Object    

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("A1:A" & lr)

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With RE
    .Pattern = "(http[s?]:\/\/.*(.png|.jpg))"
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
End With

For Each Cell In Rng
    If RE.test(Cell.Value) Then
        Cell.Value = RE.Execute(Cell.Value)(0)
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

**How to install your new code:**

- Copy the Excel VBA code
- Select the workbook in which you want to store the Excel VBA code
- Press `Alt+F11` to open the Visual Basic Editor
- On VB Editor, choose `Insert` --> `Module`
- Paste the copied code into the opened code window
- Save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

**To run the Excel VBA code:**

- Press `Alt+F8` to open Macro list
- Select the macro ExtractURL
- Click on Run.

**Note:**
If you want to place the output in another column, say column B, use this line instead...

```
Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = RE.Execute(Cell.Value)(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been always told that regexp slows things down

so here's a not-RegExp solution:

```
Sub main()
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Replace what:="*https", replacement:="https", lookat:=xlPart
        .Replace what:=".JPG*", replacement:=".JPG", lookat:=xlPart
    End With
End Sub
```

and should you *necessarily* need a Function:

```
Function ExtractURL(text As String)    
    ExtractURL = Mid(Left(text, InStrRev(text, ".JPG", , vbTextCompare) + 3), InStr(1, text, "https", vbTextCompare))
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not worried too much about slow performance, I'm more worried about easy - modular code to modify. Excel's built-in find/replace is kind of limited, regex is much more powerful and has better catch-alls

Comment: well, RegEx is as much powerful everything as not easy. `Find()` gets you the whole job done with 4 code lines and the `Function` job in one line. So, suit yourself. And, BTW, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

*from old instructions I once wrote*

To enter a User Defined Function (UDF):

- <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
- Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
- Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and
  paste the code into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `ExtractURL(cell_ref)` in some cell.

Comment: Can you check my edit on comment?  I needed the macro to run the UDF itself. I have about 1000 images in my file and once data gets processed another series of macros gets runned

Comment: Put your macro in the same module.  Suggest you do a search for some elementary tutorials on using VBA.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out already, its just been awhile since I did any excel VBA

Answer (score 0):

Per my original post, this is what I used. With the extractURL function defined in my problem statement

```
Sub MainTest()

Range("A1").Activate
Do
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    argCounter = argCounter + 1
Loop

For row = 1 To argCounter + 1
    Cells(row, 1).Value = ExtractURL(Cells(row, 1).Value)
Next row

End Sub
```

1. Dump code in module `alt+f11`
2. Save
3. View macro → MainTest

Comment: since you use the function to process all column A cells, then you may want to check my answer